# How to align span with inline-block attribute with other spans?

Tags: css

I need to set inline-block attribute on one of the spans to set width on it. But after that, I find it doesn't align with other "inline" spans on firefox. It works well on IE,  though. See the following html snip

```
<span class="" style="font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 22pt; background-color: rgb(229, 102, 0);">123123</span><span class="qqeditor-display-tab" style="display:inline-block;font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 22pt; width: 22px; background-color: rgb(229, 102, 0); height: 33px;">aaa</span><span style="font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 22pt; background-color: rgb(229, 102, 0);">123</span>
```

Is there a way that I can align these three spans on firefox? Thanks!

Comment: Is the height set on the SPAN with inline-block intentional? If I remove that (and move the `font-size` to a containing DIV like in http://jsfiddle.net/frozenkoi/kN3sB/ ) all the SPANs become the same height (well, almost. Firefox and Rockmelt are like 1 pixel taller.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The height on the SPAN is to make it has same height value as the other two. As you can see, if I remove it, it will taller than other spans. (Different font-family will cause different result. I don't care much about the height, if I can find a way to make the span same height and tall as other spans.)

Comment: have you tryed setting the `line-height` for a container element? Too tired to try it myself right now but I think that might help with the height of the SPANs without the `inline-block`.

Comment: @ryan, were any of the answers helpful? If so, be sure to accept the one that was the correct answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask. If not, could you provide some feedback so we can better help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This actually sounds like a `line-height` issue. Setting the `line-height` to `normal` on those elements should do the trick.

The reason why `line-height` would affect the background is because `line-height` on an `inline` element doesn't affect the height of the text (which is what you're applying the background to), while `line-height` on an `inline-block` element *does* affect the height of the element. While I could go into more detail as to how this works, I think we'd find out just how many words an example is worth, so here's an example instead:

[Example of how `line-height` affects `background` and `border` / `outline`](http://jsfiddle.net/q2fPr/).

## Source, in case jsFiddle disappears

**HTML**

```
<p class="a">normal <span class="inline">A</span><span class="inline-block">B</span></p>
<p class="b">2em <span class="inline">A</span><span class="inline-block">B</span></p>
<p class="c">.5em <span class="inline">A</span><span class="inline-block">B</span></p>
```

**CSS**

```
.a span {
    line-height:normal;
}
.b span {
    line-height:2em;
}
.c span {
    line-height:10px;
}
.inline-block {
    display:inline-block;
}

span {
    font-size:2em;
    outline:1px solid red;
    background:lime;
}
p {
    margin:2em;
    outline:1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a reference to a W3C spec that defines the behavior of `line-height` for adjusting the height of `inline-block`? The closest thing I know is http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-box-height but that does not seem to specify the behavior that I see with real world user agents.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen, this explains it in more detail: http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/WD-CSS21-20030915/visudet.html#line-height

Answer (score 0):

Is setting them all `inline-block;`, especially in a way that works [cross-browser](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-inline-block/) not acceptable?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kjE8z/)

Comment: Bookcasey, thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm thinking about setting all spans inline-block. But it's really a big change in JS code and I don't know if it will cause other issues.I hope ther's a easier way to fix it.